# How to extend/fill in the next rows with a quarter hourly value in SQL into a hourly one (MSSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I looked through the forums and found various solutions how to make from hourly into half an hour or quarter hourly data points, but when it comes to my particular problem I couldn't find a solution that works on MSSQL.

This is the type of code I have:

```
SELECT 
    time,
    sum(value) as total_hourly_value
FROM database
WHERE time >= '2021-03-02' and time < '2021-03-03'
GROUP BY time
```

My problem is that it returns values that are like this:

```
time                 total_hourly_value
02/03/2021 00:00                     50
02/03/2021 01:00                     40
02/03/2021 02:00                     30
```

What I am trying to achieve is extended aggregated hourly values in the following way:

```
time                 total_hourly_value
02/03/2021 00:00                     50
02/03/2021 00:15                     50
02/03/2021 00:30                     50
02/03/2021 00:45                     50
02/03/2021 01:00                     40
02/03/2021 01:15                     40
02/03/2021 01:30                     40
02/03/2021 01:45                     40
02/03/2021 02:00                     30
02/03/2021 02:15                     30
02/03/2021 02:30                     30
02/03/2021 02:45                     30
```

Please SQL wizards, lend your aid a foolish beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()`:

```
SELECT time + gs.n * INTERVAL '15 MINUTE' as time, total_hourly_value
FROM (SELECT time,
             sum(value) as total_hourly_value
      FROM database
      WHERE time >= '2021-03-02' and time < '2021-03-03'
      GROUP BY time
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     GENERATE_SERIES(0, 3) GS(n);
```

In SQL Server, the code would look like:

```
SELECT dateadd(minute, 15 * v.n, time) as time, total_hourly_value
FROM (SELECT time,
             sum(value) as total_hourly_value
      FROM database
      WHERE time >= '2021-03-02' and time < '2021-03-03'
      GROUP BY time
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3)) v(n)
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for the answer. I just realised I made a mistake in my question and should had specified MSSQL. Do you know if there is an alternative in MSSQL to generate_series() using your logic?

Comment: @NathanBlake . . . It really just requires some small tweaks.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Also just a comment, in case anyone in the future tries to use it. * n.n this part returned an error for me. Writing as *n fixed it!